# Need help changing values in a division dynamically according to the selection made in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I need help changing values in a division dynamically according to the selection made in the dropdown. The problem is, the items in the dropdown already has its specific value so it cannot be changed.

```
<select onChange="doChange()" id="$toChangeId"> 
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<div id="show"></div> 
<script> function doChange() { 
    var val1 = document.getElementById("$toChangeId").value; 
    document.getElementById('newPrice').innerHTML = val1; } 
</script>
```

now, in the div I want to display "x" when "a" is selected, "y" when "b" is selected and "z" when "c" is selected.

I have to pass the value for another operation. Can somebody tell me how we can pass more data from the select option to a division in the same page ?

Comment: Did u try? Please post your code..

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>

 function doChange() { 
var val1=document.getElementById("toChangeId").value; 
document.getElementById('newPrice').innerHTML = val1; }
     </script>

 <select onChange="doChange()" id="toChangeId">
 <option value="x">a</option>
 <option value="y">b</option>
 <option value="z">c</option> 
</select> 
<div id="newPrice">
</div>
```

You should pass x,y,z ..why 1,2,3

Comment: that's what the problem is about. I have to pass 1,2,3 for different operation.

Comment: @RobbinLama: Create one more function and use switch case inside that...then call both the function in select onchange separated by ';'

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear.
http://webanddesigning.com.np/ocart/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=72&search=barah
here, are different select options. thee price changes according to the selection made. But, when I click "add to cart" button, the value in the shopping cart does not changes according to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
  <select id="toChangeId">
     <option value="1">a</option> 
     <option value="2">b</option> 
     <option value="3">c</option> 
     </select> 

     <select id="show"></select> 



     <script>

     $('#toChangeId').on('change', function() {

        var value = this.value;

        if(value == 1){
            $('#show')
                     .append($('<option></option>')
                     .attr("value", x)
                     .text("x")); 
        }else if(value == 2){
            $('#show')
                     .append($('<option></option>')
                     .attr("value", y)
                     .text("y")); 

        }else{
            $('#show')
                     .append($('<option></option>')
                     .attr("value", z)
                     .text("z")); 

        }

     });
     </script>
```

Comment: is it possible to pass more than value data from a dropdown ?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear.
http://webanddesigning.com.np/ocart/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=72&search=barah
here, are different select options. thee price changes according to the selection made. But, when I click "add to cart" button, the value in the shopping cart does not changes according to the selection.

Comment: this code will not change your shopping card values. Your question is not clear, please indicate your question in a properly. and post some code related to your shopping cart.